# Query caching and take database in-memory in Sql Server like Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, caching, config

in mysql there is feature to cache large chunk of database in Memory. Using the mysql configuration file. (my.ini)

**Database in RAM** InnoDB, unlike MyISAM, uses a buffer pool to cache both indexes and row data. The bigger you set this the less disk I/O is needed to access data in tables. On a dedicated database server you may set this parameter up to 80% of the machine physical memory size. Do not set it too large, though, because competition of the physical memory may cause paging in the operating system.  Note that on 32bit systems you might be limited to 2-3.5G of user level memory per process, so do not set it too high.

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=6000M
```

**Query caching Size in my.ini**
Query cache is used to cache SELECT results and later return them without actual executing the same query once again. Having the query cache enabled may result in significant speed improvements, if your have a lot of identical queries and rarely changing tables. See the "Qcache_lowmem_prunes" status variable to check if the current value is high enough for your load.

```
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_size = 80M
```

They drastically boost db performance for a medium scale database.
Do we have similar features in SQL Server?

Comment: Yes.  Just go into SQL Server Management Studio and look for the options for setting up the memory.  SQL Server even allows you to initialize to a small memory footprint and then expand as needed.

Comment: Query cache in MySQL can actually degrade the performance queries are always changing.  SQL Server does the memory management automatically and seems like SQL Server tries to load as much data into memory as possible.  But yes MySQL is so much more configurable.  We migrated to MySQL and happy with performance and simplicity and flexibility.  Not to mention six figure saving on licensing cost.